# KEYCODE_BACK is not getting fired in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an app with nested fragments.In that i have contact us fragment with some edittext fields and submit button.
When user doesn't change any fields and click back nothing special happens everything would be normal.But when he enters some data and press back button without submitting them then an alert should pop-up showing a warning to the user.If he clicks OK then he should goto back.

For this i want to override back button functionality in my fragment.
so i did this.

```
 public class ContactUs extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
EditText txtname, txtEmail, txtPhone, txtDescription;
Button btnSend;
DatabaseConnection myDB;
View view = null;
int j = 0;
static boolean changed=false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view            = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_us, container, false);
    btnSend         = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    txtname         = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail        = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtPhone        = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtDescription  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    myDB=new DatabaseConnection(getActivity());




    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "oncreate view", 2000).show();

    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new onBackListener());

    }
```

And this is my onBackListener

```
    private class onBackListener implements OnKeyListener{



    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if (changed==true) {



                    AlertDialog.Builder alert=new        AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    alert.setTitle("Delete entry")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Navigate?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            changed=false;
                            getActivity().onBackPressed();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();


                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "back", 2000).show();
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
            }


            return true;

        }
        return onKey(v,keyCode,event);

    }
```

here **changed** is a boolean value which gets changed when text changes in fields(implemented textwatcher for this).If user press submit button again this values changes to false.

Everything is ok.When i open contactus fragment and click back this event is fired but when i change something in textfields and click back button the event is not firing...
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you no need to override back listener. Just override onBackPressed() for that.

Comment: how can we override onBackPressed()  inside fragment?

Comment: Yes you are right. it is not possible. Keycode_back will fire in controlling view. i mean FragmentActivity. From there you can access all your fragments. for this you may have to declare every variables declared inside the fragment should be a static